# Concatenating vectors created in a function for multiple simulations

Tags: r, arrays, vector

I created a function in R that creates a single dimension vector of varying length (size 1 to hundreds+) - code at bottom. I would like to do two things that I hope are quite simple for someone much more experienced in R than me.

For context, this function simulates a disease outbreak using a branching process with a negative binomial offspring distribution from a single index case. Each position in the vector represents an individual, and each integer represents the number of secondary cases caused by that individual.

For instance, `[3 0 1 0 1 0]` indicates there were six cases that transmitted the respective number of secondary cases. More specifically, it means:

- The index case transmitted to `3` secondary cases (first position in the vector) to the next generation.
- Of those three cases, the first case had `0` secondary cases, the second had `1` secondary case, and the third had `0` (positions 2:4 in the vector).
- The one case in the following generation also transmitted `1` case (position 5), which  had `0` secondary cases (position 6), so the process exited the loop and the vector outputs.
- If an index case transmitted no infections, the vector would simply be `[0]`.

While this is a start, I would like to improve it in the following two ways:

1. First, each time the loop continues it is a new "generation." I would like to create a `2 x n` matrix that would denote the corresponding generation. For example, the data for the example above would look like this:

   ```r
   ##' Example desired dataset of running the function
   ##' Index case transmits to three others (generation 1)
   ##' Those three transmit to 0, 1, and 0, respectively (generation 2)
   ##' The single case (Gen 3) transmits to 0 (gen 4) and the function exits the loop
   generation1 <- c(1,2,2,2,3,4)
   secondary.cases1 <- c(3,0,1,0,1,0)
   example.matrix1 <- cbind(generation1, secondary.cases1)
   print(example.matrix1)

   #      generation1 secondary.cases1
   # [1,]           1                3
   # [2,]           2                0
   # [3,]           2                1
   # [4,]           2                0
   # [5,]           3                1
   # [6,]           4                0
   ```
2. Second, the function is only for a single outbreak. For my final data, I need to simulate this a number of times (i.e. 2000), and concatenate all of these vectors. Also, similarly to 1 above, have a number denoting the corresponding simulation number. For instance, the final dataset would look like this

   ```r
   ##' Example desired dataset of three simulations:
   ##' sim1 producing a vector of [3 0 1 0 1 0] in four generations
   ##' sim2 producing a vector of [2 0 0] in three generations
   ##' sim3 producing a vector of [0] in the first generation
   simulation2 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3)
   generation2 <- c(1,2,2,2,3,4,1,2,3,1)
   secondary.cases2 <- c(3,0,1,0,1,0,2,0,0,0)
   example.matrix2 <- cbind(simulation2, generation2, secondary.cases2)
   print(example.matrix2)
   #       simulation2 generation2 secondary.cases2
   #  [1,]           1           1                3
   #  [2,]           1           2                0
   #  [3,]           1           2                1
   #  [4,]           1           2                0
   #  [5,]           1           3                1
   #  [6,]           1           4                0
   #  [7,]           2           1                2
   #  [8,]           2           2                0
   #  [9,]           2           3                0
   # [10,]           3           1                0
   ```

The function is below. For the first issue, I tried to count each iteration as a generation and create a vector. For the second issue, I tried nesting this function in another function. Both of these things  would not work properly (with my lack of expertise, that is). After hours on hours of trying independently, I am reaching out for help. Any advice would be MUCH appreciated!

```
##' The following function creates a single vector of 
##' secondary cases from a negative binomially distributed offspring distribution
##' Each row represents a specific individual in the chain of transmission, 
##' and the integer indicates how many secondary cases the individual transmitted
##' (0 indicates no secondary transmission from the index case)
##' This function only does a single outbreak. I will need to replicate this.
##' @param r0 Average number of secondary infections per each infectious individual - keep r0<1 so Pr(Extinction)=1
##' @param k Dispersion parameter of NB distribution (0-infinity)
##' @param index Number of index cases initiating the cluster (typically 1)
##' @param max_gen Maximum number of generations this loop should go through, to avoid hanging with near infinite loops. 
#########################################################################################################
#########################################################################################################
nbbp.individual<-function(r0,k,index=1,max_gen){
  G1<-rnbinom(index,size=k,mu=r0) #Does the first iteration outside fo the while to avoid problems
  cases<-G1 #initiates the number of cases in the first generation
  sumCases<-G1 #since G1 will be a single integer, this is somewhat repeative but comes into play later in the loop
  gen<-1 #initiates the generation for setting the max generations (to avoid hanging of near infinite loops)
  gencount<-0
    while (sumCases>0 && (missing(max_gen)||(gen<max_gen))){
      gen<-gen+1
      individuals<-rep(1,sumCases) #This creates a single vector of 1's to simulate the single individuals in the generaiton (i.e.[1 1 1 1]
      secondaryCases<-rnbinom(individuals,size=k,mu=r0) #This creates a vector of integers, each one corresponding to the 
                                                        #number of secondary cases for each "individual" (i.e. [0 2 0 4])
      sumCases<-sum(secondaryCases) #this sums the generation for purposes of the loop
      cases<-c(cases, secondaryCases) #This appends the individuals for each generation
    }
  return(cases)
}
#########################################################################################################
#########################################################################################################

##' If you highlight this and run it over and over, it is essentially running multiple simulations of 
##' individual tranmission chains
##' You will see that "test" mainly sticks to 0, but can range to the hundreds
test<-nbbp.individual(0.9,0.25,1,20)
print(test)
```

Comment: I am not so sure, if matrices are a good data type to represent that kind of information. For visualization yes. But I think, you need either structures or trees. And rather nested lists than vectors.

Comment: Thank you Gwang-Jin Kim for the recommendations on how to better manage the data. Some of my analysis will need the full vector, but other may better utilize the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have one solution that should solve concatenating all the vectors, and also incorporate the helpful comments regarding list-type data that @Gwang-jin Kim gave, by nesting the original function in another function:

```
nbbp.sims<-function(num_sim,r0,k,index=1,max_gen){
  list.data<-replicate(num_sim,nbbp.individual(r0,k,index,max_gen))
  vector.data<-unlist(list.data, use.names = FALSE)
  return(vector.data) #can change this to list.data if I need the list data
}
```

The `list.data` returns a list of length `num_sim` while the `unlist` function creates a single vector from the list.

This may not be the most elegant way, however, so happy to hear improvements. This does not resolve adding the generation or simulation id numbers.